# Angular don't update UI as needed

Tags: angularjs

I'm writing tree editor on Angular. How it works:

1. There is "source" object with tree structure, nested objects (`$scope.root_item`);
2. To show tree I flatten it, creating a list of items based on "source" tree structure and `ng-repeat` that list (`$scope.flatten_tree2` function).

Most of operations work ok - if you add, delete, move item up or down, then html is updated accordingly.

But when you move item left (detach from current parent and attach to parent's parent) or right (detach item from current parent and attach to upper sibling) then html isn't updated well. While both source tree structure and flatten tree list is correct.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ctfuLc02/

You could press buttons on the right. When you press < or > you'll see that html isn't corrent, though data (printed in console) is fine. In particular tr class is invalid. html after pressing ">" on 2.2 actually looks strange, because ng-class is valid, but real class attr isn't (when you move 2.2 to the right it's level is 3):

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in flatten_tree2()" ng-include="'fl2_item.inc.html'" ng-class="'level-' + 3" class="ng-scope level-2">
```

**Update**

Answer to myself - I've managed to make it work by using `angular.copy`. Instead of moving the same item from one parent to another I now create a copy of item:

```
$scope.move_fl2 = function(item, dir) {
    var parent = item['_parent'];
    var index = item['_index'];

    var events = parent['events'];

    // ...

    if (dir == 'left') {
        var parent_parent_events = item['_parent']['_parent']['events'];
        var parent_parent_index = parent_parent_events.indexOf(parent);
        // was: parent_parent_events.splice(parent_parent_index + 1, 0, item);
        parent_parent_events.splice(parent_parent_index + 1, 0, angular.copy(item));
        $scope.del_fl2(item);
    }
    else if (dir == 'right') {
        var upper_item = parent['events'][index - 1];
        upper_item['events'] = (upper_item['events'] || []);
        // was: upper_item['events'].push(item);
        upper_item['events'].push(angular.copy(item));
        $scope.del_fl2(item);
    }
};
```

Still answer with explanation why this helped would be good.